# How i can install windows 7 on ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7

I wanna install windows 7 on ubuntu. When i boot windows 7 dvd then it stuck on boot screen. Help me to install windows 7 on ubuntu. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to dual boot or run it in a Virtual Machine?

Comment: I want remove ububtu totally then wanna install windows 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) I didn't get back to your question in time before you posted your comment, but this is the correct duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If the DVD disk with Windows 7 is made in a correct way, and the computer is working well (including the DVD drive hardware and target internal drive), the installer can do the job without any pre-formatting or other preparations.

Windows will overwrite Ubuntu and whatever data was written to the target drive.

1. If there are problems it could depend on the computer hardware, or the installed system in the DVD disk. You should check these things separately.
2. Windows and the computer should match. For example, you cannot install 64-bit Windows in a 32-bit computer, and you cannot install 32-bit Windows in a computer running in UEFI mode.
3. Or maybe the burning failed. You can try again, and use the lowest possible burning speed, when you burn the DVD disk.

Please tell us more detailed information about the computer hardware and settings. It helps us help you.